# Organize column in ascending order in R

Tags: r, string, indexing, dplyr, tidyr

I need to manipulate the string so that my files can ascend in the following order: `[1,1,1]`, `[1,1,2]` `[1,1,3]`....`[1,2,1]` and so on. Any insights as to how I can do this?

In Sample.Name I need to organize what's in the square brackets to ascend like so: `[1,1,1]`, `[1,1,2]` `[1,1,3]`...`[1,2,1]` etc.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VowgZ.png)
See image for table. I tried using the split function and introducing leading zeros and couldn't get it to work. I am new here so ago easy on me please.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? No one wants to click on an image of a table, especially as you can't run it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If the string is always the same except for the contents of the square brackets, you can just `sort()` it and it will return in the desired order, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is as follows.

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(Sample.Name = c("TMA_1314_Core[1,1,2]_[66421,20799].im3",
                                 "TMA_1314_Core[1,1,1]_[66421,20799].im3", 
                                 "TMA_1314_Core[1,1,4]_[66421,20799].im3",
                                 "TMA_1314_Core[1,1,3]_[66421,20799].im3"))
```

**Code**

```
Index <- stringr::str_extract(df$Sample.Name, "\\[(\\s*(.*?)\\])") %>% 
                     gsub(pattern = "\\]|\\[", replacement = "") %>% 
                                strsplit(",") %>% 
                                           sapply(.,function(x) as.numeric(paste(x, collapse = ""))) %>% 
                                                       order
df[Index,]
```

**Output**

```
> df[Index,]
[1] "TMA_1314_Core[1,1,1]_[66421,20799].im3"
[2] "TMA_1314_Core[1,1,2]_[66421,20799].im3"
[3] "TMA_1314_Core[1,1,3]_[66421,20799].im3"
[4] "TMA_1314_Core[1,1,4]_[66421,20799].im3"
```

Comment: Thank you thats really helpful, but "TMA_1314..." is 188 rows, so is there a simpler way so I don't have to make a vector with 188 names in it?

Comment: also now it is calling TMA_1314...[1,1,10] TMA_1314..[1,1,1] instead...which is not what I want because each sample has an value attached to it which is area in square microns

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What is the output if you do `df <- mydata2_wide` and then execute the above code?